# Photo captions not showing up on photos when viewed slideshow mode in Photos.app

Tags: macos, photos.app

The captions I added to my photos in iPhoto are not showing up when I play slideshows in Photo. I can still see that the information is there when I click on a photo's Info in the album view.

Is there a way to have the captions show up in slideshow mode in Photos.app?

Answer (score 1):

There are no settings for this, and it does not appear to be possible.

This is further confirmed by [MacWorld's article](http://www.macworld.com/article/2893000/4-things-iphoto-can-do-that-photos-cant-yet.html) on "4 things iPhoto can do that Photos can't (yet)".